# How do you have multiple tokens for HTTP POST Authorization?

Tags: python, post, python-requests, http-headers, http-authentication

An HTTP GET returned:

```json
"Access-Token": "<Long Hex Access Token>",
"Refresh-Token": "<Long Hex Refresh Token>"
```

I need to send those in the header as an authorization for all requests so I tried:

```py
response = requests.get("<URL>", headers={"Authorization":"Access-Token <Long Hex Access Token> Refresh-Token <Long Hex Refresh Token>"})
```

which always returns: `<Response [401]>`

I cant figure out what I'm doing wrong. I know that the tokens are correct because I checked the refresh token and it returned `<Response [200]>`

Comment: Try using separate key/value pairs `{"Access-Token": ..., "Refresh-Token": ...}` instead of just one `Authentication` key.

Comment: @JohnGordon, I changed it to `requests.get("<URL>", headers={"Access-Token":"<Long Hex Access Token>","Refresh-Token":"<Long Hex Refresh Token>"})` and I still get `<Response [401]>`

Comment: Is there documentation for the url you're trying to access, that specifies what headers you need to send?

Answer (score 1):

I have realized my error. I misread the API that I was using and some syntactical mistakes.

The proper solution is:

```py
response = requests.get("<URL>", headers={"Authorization":"<Long Hex Access Token>"})
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your access token a JWT bearer token? If so, you need to prefix the word `Bearer` to your long URL-encoded string.

`headers={"Authorization":"Bearer <Long Hex Access Token>"})`

But this is just a guess without having the documentation for the API you are trying to use.